# Catch up text from voice Interactive Canvas?

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am designing a web screen with Interactive Canvas. I want to capture the text from the voice of the user speaking in the input box. It's similar to `conv.input.raw` in **functions / index.js** but I don't know what to do in **public / index.html** 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have text in `conv.input.raw` in functions / index.js you need to pass it to website using interactiveCanvas api.

```
conv.ask(new HtmlResponse({
  data: {
    userEnteredData: conv.input.raw
  }
}));
```

And from website you will get it in callback of interactive canvas

```
interactiveCanvas.ready({
   onUpdate(data) {
       console.log('user entered text = ', data.userEnteredData);
       document.getElementById("textBox").value = data.userEnteredData;
   }
});
```